# jinja2: substituting variables into a for loop statement

Tags: for-loop, iteration, jinja2

Let's say I have the following python dictionary:

```
d = { "name0": "Johnny",
      "name1": "Stephanie",
      "name2": "Jake",
      "name3": "Nicole",
      "name4": "Cody"
    }
```

I'm passing this dictionary to a jinja2 template using flask. How can I iterate over these names in the template? Here's what I have so far:

```
{% for i in range(5) %}
  {% for name in d.name{{ i }} %}
    {{ name }}
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I know this isn't the best way to do this (this example simplifies my data to the extreme). Best way would probably be to put all the names in a list called "names" and embed that within the dictionary like so: `d = { "names": ["Johnny", Stephanie", etc.] }`. I'm wondering if my specific question has a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the dictionary like you can in python:

```
{% for k, v in d.items() %}
    {{ v }}
{% endfor %}
```